# How can i make condition when date in db less than date now 7 days in event mysql?

Tags: mysql, events

I want make Event in my mysql but the problem is in where condition , I want make update my column if date today is greater than date in databse more or equal 7 days...
this is how the date looks like in mysql  **2017-03-02 11:22:43**

```
update mytable
set status=0
where date(insert_at) < date('-7 day')
```

Any help i will be gratfull

Answer (score 1):

```
where insert_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```